# Chequear un frame con selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

estoy intentando hacer un log-in automatizado a HBO Max (Propositos solo de aprendizaje) y ya pude lograr typear tanto contraseña como mail en sus campos correspondientes y darle al enter para ingresar. Lo que me falta es chequear si el Login da bien o tira fail.
Sé que para eso tengo que chequear si el texto correspondiente al fail se encuentra en un frame, pero no sé exactamente como hacer switch a ese frame, no tiene nombre ni tiene ID por lo cual estoy re perdido con eso.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQCwf.png

Eso es lo que veo al inspeccionar el frame que debo hacerle switch

¿Alguna idea de como hacerle switch?

(Perdonen si parece que no busque en la documentación oficial, lo busqué pero hay cosas que no entendí)

Answer (score 0):

Usa el selector css

Debes obtenerlo usando chrome:

1. sobre el mensaje a buscar: Click derecho  >> Inspeccionar
2. En la seccion abierta: Click derecho >> Copiar >> Copiar selector

luego

```
selector_copiado= "pega aqui lo anterior que copiaste con google chrome"
elemento = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector_copiado)
```

También es posible hacerlo por XPath aunque no tenga "Id". Recomiendo que pruebes a copiarlos desde el menú que describo lineas arriba (Copiar XPath y Copiar XPath completo), y probarlos en este codigo:

```
xpath_copiado = "pega aqui lo anterior que copiaste con google chrome"
elemento = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_copiado)
```

Si no tienes exito recomiendo también que actualices la pregunta y compartas las 3 cadenas: selector css, y las otras dos xpath

Answer (score -3):

Para obtener el contenido de un iframe con Selenium en Python, primero debes usar la función find_element_by_xpath() para encontrar el elemento iframe en la página. Una vez que tienes una referencia al elemento iframe, puedes usar la función switch_to_frame() para cambiar el contexto de Selenium a ese iframe. Luego, puedes usar las funciones normales de Selenium para buscar y interactuar con los elementos dentro del iframe. Por ejemplo:

```
# Encuentra el elemento iframe en la página
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="mi_iframe"]')

# Cambia el contexto de Selenium al iframe
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)

# Busca un elemento dentro del iframe
elemento = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@id="mi_parrafo"]')

# Obtiene el contenido del elemento
contenido = elemento.text
```

En este ejemplo, primero se busca el elemento iframe mediante el XPATH igual  en la página. Luego, se cambia el contexto de Selenium al iframe encontrado. Finalmente, se busca un elemento p con el atributo id igual a mi_parrafo dentro del iframe y se obtiene su contenido.

Comment: pero pero.. dice que no tiene id... estas seguro que esta respuesta la escribiste vos???

Comment: Ni idea si la escribió el o simplemente no leyó eso. Igualmente pude dirigirme usando Xpath de otra forma.